# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have MVC5 application, this error comes suddenly while my application successfully running, and also sometimes gone(and sometimes not) after rebuild and run application again.
Anyone can help..

[image: This error page comes while running my application.]

Comment: Try to open your visual studio in **elevated mode**, then try with clean then build and after successful build try to run it.

Comment: Can you please tell me, How to open visual studio in 'elevated mode' what does it mean..

Comment: Go to visual studio shortcut Icon, right click and check for `Open visual studio in Administrative mode`. It will open VS in elevated mode **(If you are using windows operating system)**. This is not a perfect solution, but this might resolve your issue